# Service with complexType with a single byte sequence property, Bug?

Tags: c#, wcf, xsd, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer

I'm trying to consume a service (built and hosted in Java) using WCF which has the following XSD contained

`<xs:simpleType name="SimpleByteType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:unsignedByte"/>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:complexType name="ArrayOfBytes">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="SimpleByteType-item" type="tns:SimpleByteType" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="ArrayOfBytes" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfBytes"/>`

When I request data from this service I get the following error:

> "Base64 sequence length (1) not valid. Must be a multiple of 4."

This is odd as the xml that is returned is something like this:

```
<ArrayOfBytes>
  <SimpleByteType-item>0</SimpleByteType-item>
  <SimpleByteType-item>1</SimpleByteType-item>
  <SimpleByteType-item>2</SimpleByteType-item>
</ArrayOfBytes>
```

So, it is not Base64 encoded at all. Apparently dotnet, consumes this xsd and makes it a byte[] which should contain base64 encoded data resulting in the error.

Am I doing something wrong here, or is this a bug in the way WCF interprets the XSD? The proper identifier for base64 encode data would be a type base64Binary see: http://www.w3.org/2002/ws/databinding/examples/6/09/Base64BinaryElement/

Another thing which leads me to think this is a bug is that changing the XSD (the restriction in it) from

```
<xs:restriction base="xs:unsignedByte"/>
```

to

```
<xs:restriction base="unsignedInt"/>
```

fixes the issue. Which obviously should have nothing to do with the content being base64 encoded or not.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you are seeing is actually expected.  As you already noticed, WCF expects base64Binary encoded data in place of byte[].

I did some research and found that this implementation conforms to the [SOAP 1.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383517) which states: 
The recommended representation of an opaque array of bytes is the 'base64' encoding defined in XML Schemas [10][11], which uses the base64 encoding algorithm defined in 2045 [13].

For reference, here is a link to the type mappings between XSD and .Net Framework: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719879(v=vs.71).aspx.  I also found the type mappings for ORACLE’s JAVA: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3669/bnazt/index.html which also conforms to the SOAP spec, it is interesting that the XSD for the JAVA service in question does not follow the recommendation.

Your workaround looks good to me.  You could also use xs:short for better memory usage. You might need to cast values to byte in your application.

Comment: As far as I can see, the point you're referencing concerns a field which is supposed to have a single value (a base64 encode byte[] in which the individual bytes together make up a single value). However the problem is within the element of a complex type which is a sequence of single byte values. The first, can only be a byte[] as a field in .Net while the latter can be a List<byte> as well as it's just a number of byte values which have nothing to do with each other.